# How to change specific characters at the end of ALL hyperlinks w/in webpage with jQuery

Tags: jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiXPF.png)
Hey all,

I have a list of items with titles that are hyperlinks to the actual content.  The code below removes the .aspx part from the title, but for some reason the code also changes all titles for each item to be the same.

Each item should have a unique title with the .aspx removed.

Any help is appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var val = $(".dfwp-item .link-item a").html();
   $(".dfwp-item .link-item a").html(val.substring(0, val.length -5));
});
```

I expect to see each unique title, per item, to ONLY have the .aspx characters removed from the end.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, please clarify your doubt/problem. Or use sample problem to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

without jQuery...

```
const anchor = document.querySelectorAll('.dfwp-item .link-item a')

anchor.forEach(a => {
    a.textContent = a.textContent.replace('.aspx', '')
})
```

using jQuery (but I'm not sure about)...

```
const anchor = $('.dfwp-item .link-item a')

$.each(anchor, function (key, a) {
    a.text(a.text().replace('.apsx', ''));
})
```